# Angular form sending on different endpoints

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got form on page with three forms groups

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  profile: this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [''],
    description: [''],   
  }),

  members: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      experience: [''],
    }),
  ]),

  drinks: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      description: [''],
    }),
  ]),
});
```

In my situation I need to send this three form groups on three different endpoints.

```
sendForm() {  
    const team = this.form.controls.profile.value;
    const members = this.form.controls.members.value; 
    const drinks = this.form.controls.drinks.value);

    this.teamService.sendTeam(team).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
    this.teamService.sendMembers(members).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
    this.teamService.sendDrinks(drinks).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

What is the best practices for such requests? I know that three subscribes isn't the best way to do it, but certainly the easiest one. Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
 

 sendForm() {
          const team = this.form.controls.profile.value;
          const members = this.form.controls.members.value; 
          const drinks = this.form.controls.drinks.value);
    
        forkJoin(
          this.teamService.sendTeam(team),
          this.teamService.sendMembers(members),
          this.teamService.sendDrinks(drinks),
        ).subscribe(([team, members, drinks]) => {
          
         // any function
          
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const teamObservable$ = this.teamService.sendTeam(team);
const memberObservable$ = this.teamService.sendMembers(members);
const serviceObservable$ = this.teamService.sendDrinks(drinks);

combineLatest(teamObservable$, memberObservable$, serviceObservable$)
       .subscribe(([teamResponse, memberResponse, serviceResponse]) => { 
})
```